# Join 2 webservices in client side or server side

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, web-services, mongodb-query, software-design

I am working as service developer.

My web-service have support 2 method: get a student by student id and get class by student id.
Web UI actually need a data that is a student with class information embedded in.

So  I need to query student by id then keep in student variable, then query class by student id then classbyStudent. Then try to embed the class variable to the student variable.

So Where I should write these code above?
Should I write a third service to serve the student with class information?
Or leave it for client-side (angular Js)

Comment: You create the code where it makes sense. There is no right and wrong way with these type of design decision only successful and unsuccessful.

Comment: Hi Namphibian, Would you give me an example or a real case?